# Solution for database query and comparison in NiceLabel

Tags: python, mysql, sql, vb.net

I'm currently using a program called **NiceLabel** to create a form that prints labels for a production environment. The current idea is that there are 4 entry forms tied to a database, the first form will query and select the relevant entry in the database and the last entry fields would be for comparing the entries under their respective columns. If all the data in all the forms match it will allow you to print a label.

I have no practical experience actually developing, this is my first venture and I'm pretty lost. I have included a screenshot of the front end form itself, the program supports python/vb scripting and SQL queries.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr0Tl.png]

Comment: lol We aren't going to do it for you! It's not really clear on how the software works. Start by installing visual studio. Basic is like talking to a machine. If you don't mind reading then go ahead and read and google. There's tons of help on vb.net and SQL

Comment: Hey, sorry if I wasn't clear. I just need a decent resource on how to even figure out how to compare a database entry to a variable entry. I just literally don't know anything past psuedocode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this should not be considered a coding/tutorial service. It is up to you to do the research and attempts. We're just here to help you with any problems you might encounter along the way. Please take a moment to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @tylrat93 Sorry, you came to the wrong place. we will help ya if you show some code

Comment: First, you need to find out the language. VB script is different from VB.Net.